# how to authenticate json data which are present in the remote server using spring security

Tags: json, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi i am havving the login page where username and password i m entering ,i m converting it to the first json and then sending to the url.i m doing this without any spring security so is there any way for authenticating this data..before sending to server it should be first authenticated..and then it should converted to json..
suppose i m havving login page like this

```
<form:form method="post" action="">
<input:path="username" name="j_username"/>
<input:password path="password" name="j_password"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

and userlogin.java for setter and getter 
like get username ,get password  and service is loginuser for converting data to json and sending to the server and controller for get and post method of login.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you somehow rephrase it? Or maybe include a simple and clear example?

Comment: @PavelHoral,please check my edit section and let me know..if any solution?